# Temperature damping parameter in lammps

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, polymers, water, temperature

I need help on how to set `Tdamping` in MD simulation. In Lammps documentation it is mentioned that the typical value is 100 for nvt, but when I put this value to my system which contain 46750 atoms at 500 K it give me error like bond atom is missing but when I use smaller system with 300 K is going works well.

What is the reason for such a behaviour ?

Comment: The error "bond atom is missing" is typically associated with atoms moving too rapidly and exiting the simulation box. There can be ***various reasons*** for this occurrence. Without additional details (LAMMPS script, conditions, structure etc.) it's impossible to provide a definitive solution to your problem.

Also, regarding the choice of `tdamp`, the LAMMPS manual advises:"A good choice for many models is a `Tdamp` of around $100$ timesteps.". This implies that `tdamp` should be set to $100 \times dt$ (the length of the timestep), not simply equal to $100$, unless of course $dt$ is $1.0$.